# if statement with getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

If i try to use if statement with docoument.getElementById(id).src== something it doesnt work but when just use document.getElementById().src=Something  it works...I get no error or anything when I click on on the image.

```
 //  dice function
function keepDice(id){


//document.getElementById(id).src="diceX1.gif"; <<<<<<<<<< works... 

if(document.getElementById(id).src=="dice1.gif") document.getElementById(id).src="diceX1.gif";
else if(document.getElementById(id).src=="dice2.gif") document.getElementById(id).src="diceX2.gif";
else if(document.getElementById(id).src=="dice2.gif") document.getElementById(id).src="diceX3.gif";
else if(document.getElementById(id).src=="dice3.gif") document.getElementById(id).src="diceX4.gif";
else if(document.getElementById(id).src=="dice4.gif") document.getElementById(id).src="diceX5.gif";
else if(document.getElementById(id).src=="dice5.gif") document.getElementById(id).src="diceX6.gif";

}

functionfunction roll()
    {

    var diceSum=0; 


    if (countClicks()==true){
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)

    {

    d[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    document.getElementById("d"+i).src="dice"+d[i]+".gif";
    diceSum+=d[i];

    } 



    if (/1234|2345|3456/.test(d.join("").replace(/(.)\1/,"$1"))) alert("small straight");
    else if (/12345|23456/.test(d.join("").replace(/(.)\1/,"$1"))) alert("large straight");
    else if (/(.)\1{2}(.)\2|(.)\3(.)\4{2}/.test(d.join("").replace(/(.)\1/,"$1")))    alert("full house");

        ofAKindScore=diceSum;
        document.getElementById("rolls").value=ClickCount;
        diceSum=0;     
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 15; i++){


        document.getElementById("s"+i).value='';
        taken[i]= false;

        }


    }
```

---

```
<div style="border: solid 3px #0000ff">
<img  id='d0' onClick="keepDice('d0')" src="dice0.gif">

<img  id='d1' onClick="keepDice('d1')" src="dice0.gif">

<img  id='d2' onClick="keepDice('d2')" src="dice0.gif">

<img  id='d3' onclick="keepDice('d3')" src="dice0.gif">

<img  id='d4' onClick="keepDice('d4')" src="dice0.gif">

<p> Rolls Left: <input id='rolls' type='text' value='3' size="3"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could probably use `this` or `event.target` to get at the element being click on.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statements are looking for `dice1.gif`, `dice2.gif`, `dice3.gif`, etc. But all of the images start as `dice0.gif`. The code never checks for `dice0.gif`.

Comment: actually have I another function thats changing the image every time I run it.  Which should be changing the source.  here is the function

Comment: @bimm3rBoy: When you fetch the `element.src`, it's going to return the fully qualified URL, so a comparison to just the local path isn't going to match. Instead, you can check to see if the `.src` *ends* with the value you're comparing.

Comment: Squint you are right!! I just did an alert of src and it's showing the whole path... How can I just compare with the name of the file?? is it *+dice.gif?